# Weil-Petersson norm of a Beltrami form

Tags: teichmuller-theory, weil-petersson-metric

I'm reading Scott Wolpert's paper *Noncompleteness of the Weil-Petersson metric for Teichmüller Space*.

He defines a path leading to the boundary of Teichmüller Space by giving surfaces $R_t$ determined by Beltrami differentials $$\frac{t-1}{t+1}\frac{\overline{\phi dz^2}}{|\phi dz^2|}$$ for $t\geq 1$ and $-\phi dz^2$ a Jenkins-Strebel differential on an initial surface $R$.

To compute the length of this path, he calculates the tangent vector to this curve at $R_t$ is the Beltrami differential $$\frac{1}{2t}\frac{\overline{(d\zeta_t)^2}}{|(d\zeta_t)^2|},$$ where $\zeta_t$ are the natural coordinates on $R_t$.

He computes $$\left|\left|\frac{1}{2t} \frac{\overline{(d\zeta_t)^2}}{|(d\zeta_t)^2|}\right|\right|_t = \sup_\phi \frac{\left|\left[\frac{1}{2t} \frac{\overline{(d\zeta_t)^2}}{|(d\zeta_t)^2|}, \phi\right]\right|}{||\phi||_t} \leq \sup_\phi \frac{\left|\left[\frac{1}{2t} \frac{\overline{(d\zeta_t)^2}}{|(d\zeta_t)^2|}, \phi\right]\right|}{\left(\sum_j \int_{A_j} |\phi|^2\lambda_j^{-2}\right)^{1/2}},$$
where the summation is over the annuli $A_j$ in the annular decomposition of $R_t$ and $\lambda_j$ is the hyperbolic metric on $A_j$.

His next sentence confuses me. He notes that $\lambda_j$ does not depend on the imaginary part of $\zeta_{j,t}$ and "we see that the extremal value of the last quotient is estimated by $\phi = (d\zeta_t)^2$".

Can anyone clarify why this particular $\phi$ achieves the supremum?

Comment: $\lambda_j$ is a Poincare type metric(not really Poincare metric), so it is real :) . We must choose such $\lambda_j$ which have log log singularities to get the boundedness of such norms.